# Тема Wordpress. При описании page-title в style.css в браузере ничего не происходит. Кеш чистил

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <div class="content">
<h2> <class='page-title'>Cтраница: <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post-main">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?> <span>(<?php the_time('j.m.Y'); ?>)</span></h1>
        <div class="post">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- post navigation -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- no posts found -->
<?php endif; ?>

        </div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>


.page-title{
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    color: #3F282F;
    font: 20px Verdana;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc; 
}
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Не надо плодить вопросы.

Comment: Хочу разобратся. Правда не получается. Я два раза продублировал вопрос один со скриншотом другой без. Вы мне в ответе на предыдущий вопрос сильно помогли.

Comment: @Владимир, повтор вопроса - неприемлемое действие. Так вы только минусов нахватаете и ответ вряд ли получите. Вам надо не новый вопрос-повтор задавать, но старый редактировать, добавляя детали/пояснения.

Comment: Правой кнопкой мыши на элементе - Просмотреть код. Откроется Dev tools. В нем в правой части - computed. И смотрите, откуда ваши стили берутся http://take.ms/eM0WC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватает `div` перед `class="page-title"`

Comment: Хорошо подметили. Только, скорее, он хотел дать класс h2, так что `<h2 class="page-title"`

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Я прохожу уроки по созданию темы вордпрес. Блог путешественника. Они бесплатные есть в интернете. 9 уроков. Конец 8 урока автор создает page-title (више видно как он вызлядит) к нему подключает стили, я указал какие. page-title подключился а стили нет.

Comment: Спасибо KAGG Design я открил Dev tools, и внес изменения в файле стилей в .post. Начало получатся. Но не так как показано в видеоуроке.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/home/travel

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSpT0Ze6jFY

Comment: Выслал ссылку на мою тему wordpress в дроббокс и видеоурок который прохожу. Последние 5 минут урока создание page-title.

Comment: <h2> <div class='page-title'>Cтраница: <?php the_title(); ?></h2> - так сработало. Ответ div.

Comment: h2 перед h1 ? Вас SEO-шники изнасилуют)))